# Gitlab API create a composer package with `composer.json` outside root directory

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

I'm trying to create a private composer package with `.gitlab-ci.yml` using [gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/packages/composer.html#create-a-package).

The problem is that my `composer.json` file is inside `app` directory and I'm getting `composer.json not found` error while running pipeline. Any ideas how can I fix it or there's no solution for that case ?

Structure of the project looks like this:

```
.
├── app/
│   └── composer.json
└── .gitlab-ci.yml
```

The `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apk add curl
    - 'curl --header "Job-Token: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" --data tag=$CI_COMMIT_TAG "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/composer"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always change directory (`cd`) in your script:

```yaml
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apk add curl
  script:
    - cd app
    - 'curl --header "Job-Token: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" --data tag=$CI_COMMIT_TAG "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/composer"'
```